# Spark Cluster EC2 - SSH Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

When setting up a basic cluster using the supplied spark script for ec2, the cluster is created (1 mater, 1 slave) but I continuously get SSH hostname resolution errors.

This is because the host names are empty.

As understand it, the point of the script is that it creates the instances and so it should know the names and be able to resolve these as part of the setup.

So the question is - am I supposed to configure ec2-script before trying to launch the cluster?

Comment: You need to provide a bunch of command line arguments. Region, machine type, whatever. My guess is you omitted something or made a typo, and now the instances don't get created. What do you see in the EC2 console? Are the instances created at all?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your ec2 script invocation.